# Acceder a información de resolución de la Camara (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hace unos días estoy buscando la forma de poder acceder a una información especifica de la cámara. Lo que busco es llegar a saber en que resolución tiene configurada dicha cámara o en cuantos MP está sacando ya que es una información muy importante para una APP que estoy haciendo pero sinceramente no he logrado obtener nada.

En resumen lo que me gustaría saber es como por ejemplo, cuando buscar saber el modelo y marca de un teléfono pones (siguiente código) , si existe algo similar a la resolución actual de cámara, solo la información.

Muchas gracias

```
 public String getModelMobile() {
    String fabricante = Build.MANUFACTURER;
    String modelo = Build.MODEL;
    if (modelo.startsWith(fabricante)) {

        return modelo;
    } else {

        return fabricante + " " + modelo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es un cálculo matemático para los megapixeles, te puede servir: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6952469/determining-camera-resolution-i-e-megapixels-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 2):

La resolución de la camara debes calcularla, puedes realizarlo a partir de el alto y ancho dividido por 1,024,000, cuyo resultado sería la resolución en pixeles.

Puedes usar el siguiente método que realiza la obtención y calculo de este valor.

```
public float getCameraResolution(int CAMERA_FACING) {
    float maxRes = -1;
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, cameraInfo);
        //0 Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK
        //1 Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT
        if (cameraInfo.facing == CAMERA_FACING)
        {
            Camera camera = Camera.open(i);
            Camera.Parameters cameraParams = camera.getParameters();
            for (int j = 0;j < cameraParams.getSupportedPictureSizes().size();j++) {
                Camera.Size size = cameraParams.getPictureSize();
                int height = size.height;
                int width = size.width;
                maxRes = (height * width) / (1024000.0f);
            }
            camera.release();
        }
    }
    return maxRes;
}
```

De esta forma podrías obtener la resolución en pixeles de la cámara trasera:

```
  float resolucion = getCameraResolution(0);
```

De esta forma podrías obtener la resolución en pixeles de la cámara frontal:

```
 float resolucion = getCameraResolution(1);
```

Comment: Si, pero se puede saber cual es la resolucion que tiene configurada la camara en ese momento. Por ejemplo el telefono es de 21 MP pero yo lo tengo configurada en 5 mp. Esa información de los 5Mp se puede obtener?

Comment: Recuerda que cuando realices tus preguntas especifiques todos los detalles que deseas conocer, en este caso no se puede obtener hasta el día de hoy ya que el calculo se basa en las maximas características soportadas del dispositivo.

Comment: Gracias Jorge y la verdad crei estaba formulando bien la pregunta pero por lo visto faltaron detalles. Gracias amigo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes valerte del API [`Camera`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera?hl=es-419) para obtener los datos relevantes a las cámaras disponibles en el dispositivo.

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
 List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

En la variable `sizes` tienes una lista re las resoluciones soportadas por el hardware.

A partir del *API level 21*, [`camera2`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera?hl=es-419) es el nuevo API oficial pero, a esta fecha, no todos los fabricantes lo soportan correctamente.

Con este sería de la siguiente forma:

```
StreamConfigurationMap streamConfigurationMap = cameraCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP); 
Size[] sizes = streamConfigurationMap.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class);
```

Comment: Si, pero se puede saber cual es la resolucion que tiene configurada la camara en ese momento. Por ejemplo el telefono es de 21 MP pero yo lo tengo configurada en 5 mp. Esa información de los 5Mp se puede obtener?

Comment: La cámara como tal, el dispositivo, no "_tiene configurada_" una resolución en ningún momento. La cámara es un dispositivo que tiene la capacidad de hacer capturas en distintas resoluciones.  Cuándo haces una toma, indicas la resolución en la que la quieres. Dicho esto, puede haber un objeto o aplicación que SI tengan configurada alguna resolución, pero lo que he dicho responde tu pregunta actual. Sugiero leer [ask] y si tienes dudas adicionales, podrías escribir una nueva pregunta.